# Auto Redirect Next page in django in one to one relationship for create view

Tags: django

Suppose I've two models. one to one relationship between them.

```
class DataStamp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    male = models.IntegerField()
```

```
class DataStampProfile(models.Model):
    datastamp = models.OneToOneField(DataStamp, verbose_name=_("Data Stamp"), 
    .................
.............
```

I want to redirect DataStampProfile create page whenever new DataStamp is create.

Answer (score 0):

In your data stamp create view add a success url which will redirect the view to another view in which you can create data stamped profile. An example is shown below with generic views.

```
class DataStampCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = DataStamp
    form_class = DataStampCreateForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('add_data_stamped_profile')
```